# How do you apply twitter modal popup on fullcalendar event click

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using the fullCalendar jQuery plugin right now and I'm planning to apply the Twitter Modal Bootstrap on eventClick. How do I apply this method for my calendar plugin? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

You can accomplish that by doing something like:

```
eventClick: function(event) {
    var modal = $("#modal");
    modal.find(".modal-title").html(event.title);
    modal.modal();
}
```

For complete code and functionality see the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hoz32hs0/)

Comment: Should be accepted answer, but I prefer to reset the the html content before populating it. For example, adding in: modal.find(".modal-title").html(''); just before modal.find(".modal-title").html(event.title)

Comment: @RobertWaddell unless you have some weird issue, you don't need to do that. `,html(«string»)` should replace the entire DOM on the selector.

Comment: Agreed, but since there will already be html present after the modal is opened once, I prefer to 'reset' the modal before launching it again in case a weird issue does occur. Actually, I prefer to do this type of reset when the modal is closed, but then again I am getting even further off topic. Anyway, my intent was to suggest your answer be accepted but wanted to make my comment more than a +1 :-).

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this question and I thought this may help someone.
This code worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $calPopOver;
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: '2015-07-23',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    eventMouseover: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        $(this).children().popover({
            title: '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>',
            placement: 'right',
            content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.',
            html: true,
            container: 'body'
        });
        if($calPopOver)
            $calPopOver.popover('destroy');
        $calPopOver = $(this).children().popover('show');
    },
    eventLimit: false, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2015-07-04'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2015-07-18',
                end: '2014-07-19'
            },        
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2015-07-23'
            }
        ]
}); });
```

To get the hover effect you can change from "eventClick" to "eventMouseover"

http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/1Lmejhmx/2/